# Mutations in organisms

Tags: dna, mutations, mrna

I was researching mutations and came across an interesting question:
Do mutations occur in the DNA or mRNA of an organism? Is this more opinion that science?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNA. mRNA is transcribed from DNA.

Comment: specifically I assume that the mRNA base changes are a result of the exons, correct?

Comment: A more complete answer would be great (I could write it myself but I just wanted to give you some ideas if you wanted to expand your answer). It could be stated for example that not all mutations will ever be transcribed and that of course if there is a mutation in a coding region that is being expressed, then you'll find the mutation in the mRNA also.

Comment: Simple questions are best answered with simple answers. You can have your opinions, but in my opinion, I am often annoyed by long winded answers.

Comment: @KarlKjer Fair enough. +1

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation):

> A mutation is the **permanent alteration of the nucleotide sequence of the genome** of an organism, virus, or extrachromosomal DNA or other genetic elements.

The key word here is **genome**. A mutation is defined as something occurring in the genome, and the genome of living beings is made of DNA. Hence, mutations arise in the DNA.

A special case concerns **viruses** (which, for the record, are often not considered living beings): they can have a RNA genome, so they can have mutations in the RNA.

### **BUT!**

This **does not mean** that mRNA transcription is an error-free process! As an example, [this link](http://book.bionumbers.org/what-is-the-error-rate-in-transcription-and-translation/) gives you a nice overview on the error rate in transcription and translation,which apparently are quite high. It's just that, *by definition*, mutations arise in the genome.